# MongoDB - Return list with items surrounded with double quotes

Tags: mongodb, flask, jinja2, pymongo

I am querying MongoDB collection using `pymongo` which works fine except that the return objects are surrounded by single quotes.

Is there some setting that I can pass so that the returned objects are surrounded with double quotes?

This is how I am querying the collection:

```
with MongoClient('localhost', 27017) as client:
    db = client['somedb']
    collection = db['somecollection']
    return list(collection.find())
```

This is the output:

```
<class 'list'>: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Desired output:

```
<class 'list'>: ["a", "b", "c"]
```

This is how I am assigning data attribute:

```
<div class="card" data-mylist="{{ list_of_data }}">
```

This is how I am accessing data attribute:

```
data = $(this).data( "mylist" )
```

This is how element looks like when I inspect it:

Comment: I am adding this to data attribute to my html element and when I access it using jquery’s .data() method, it treats the value as string as opposed to an array.

Comment: Can you show the code that returns the "data" jQuery uses?

Comment: @oste-popp: updated the question

Comment: Are you using Flask? then you could use `tojson` in 
`<div class="card" data-mylist="{{ list_of_data | tojson }}">`

Comment: @oste-popp: Thanks. This is what I ended up doing to get mylist as an array in JavaScript: `<div class="card" data-mylist='{"list":{{ list_of_data | tojson }}}'>`. Please provide your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask has some standard-filters to handle python data in jinja.
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/templating/#standard-filters

`tojson` is one of them. It converts a python object to JSON.

It can be used by piping the data inside the jinja delimiter.

```
<div class="card" data-mylist="{{ list_of_data | tojson }}">
```